# How to show quoted command list?

Tags: ps, process-management

`ps -o command` shows each command on a separate line, with space separated, unquoted arguments:

```
$ ps -o command
COMMAND
bash
ps -o command
```

This can be a problem when checking whether the quoting was correct or to copy and paste a command to run it again. For example:

```
$ xss-lock --notifier="notify-send -- 'foo bar'" slock &
[1] 20172
$ ps -o command | grep [x]ss-lock
xss-lock --notifier=notify-send -- 'foo bar' slock
```

The output of `ps` is misleading - if you try to copy and paste it, the command will not do the same thing as the original. So **is there a way, similar to Bash's `printf %q`, to print a list of running commands with *correctly escaped or quoted arguments*?**

Comment: Probably not unless you go hack the source for `ps`.

Comment: Of course, if you typed it in, you probably have the original command in your shell history...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux, you can get a slightly more raw list of args to a command from `/proc/$pid/cmdline` for a given process id. The args are separated by the nul char. Try `cat -v /proc/$pid/cmdline` to see the nuls as `^@`, in your case: `xss-lock^@--notifier=notify-send -- 'foo bar'^@slock^@`.

The following perl script can read the proc file and replace the nuls by a newline and tab giving for your example:

```
xss-lock
    --notifier=notify-send -- 'foo bar'
    slock
```

Alternatively, you can get a requoted command like this:

```
xss-lock '--notifier=notify-send -- '\''foo bar'\''' 'slock'
```

if you replace the `if(1)` by `if(0)`:

```
perl -e '
  $_ = <STDIN>;
  if(1){
      s/\000/\n\t/g;  
      s/\t$//; # remove last added tab
  }else{
      s/'\''/'\''\\'\'\''/g;  # escape all single quotes
      s/\000/ '\''/;          # do first nul
      s/(.*)\000/\1'\''/;     # do last nul
      s/\000/'"' '"'/g;       # all other nuls
  }
  print "$_\n";
' </proc/$pid/cmdline
```

Comment: +1 works, but can't be used without further munging to run the command again.

Comment: @l0b0 It's the best you can get. At least on Linux it's possible, there are Unix variants that only store the command line in an ambiguous, truncated form.

Comment: this actually breaks if the process named is called from a path with apostrophes. the command name needs quoting, too.

Comment: Try `perl -ne 'print join(" ", map quotemeta, split(/\000/)), "\n"' < /proc/.../cmdline` for a quick-and-dirty re-runnable version, with excess backslashes.

Comment: Or slightly shorter, `perl -nE '$, = " "; say map quotemeta, split /\0/' /proc/.../cmdline`

Comment: @oals nice. I had thought quotemeta would provide an unreadable result, but in fact it's not too bad, you just have to notice where the `\<space>` occur.

Comment: @oals Nice! Why don't you post it as another solution?

Answer (score 2):

As meuh noted, you can get the string on Linux and NetBSD from `/proc/PID/cmdline` with arguments delimited by NUL bytes. Here is a quick and dirty way to transform them into runnable command-lines.

```
perl -ne 'print join(" ", map quotemeta, split(/\000/)), "\n"' /proc/.../cmdline
```

The output looks like:

```
xss\-lock \-\-notifier\=notify\-send\ \-\-\ \'foo\ bar\' slock
```

You can directly copypaste it to your shell to run it.

Shorter variant (requires Perl 5.10 or newer):

```
perl -nE '$, = " "; say map quotemeta, split /\0/' /proc/.../cmdline
```

And while I'm at it, a golfed version (40 bytes):

```
perl -nE'$,=" ";say map"\Q$_",split/\0/' /proc/.../cmdline
```

Answer (score 2):

As with the other answers, `/proc/${PID}/cmdline` is the key, and this is available on Linux, FreeBSD, and NetBSD.

As an alternative to `perl` and some quite complex `sed`, observe that `xargs` with the common but not standard `-0` can happily turn `␀`-terminated strings into command arguments, and (as the question says) `printf` with the common but not standard `%q` format specifier can happily turn command arguments into shell-quoted strings.

```
for i in /proc/[0-9]*/
do
    basename "$i"
    < $i/cmdline xargs -0 printf '\t%q'
    printf '\n'
done
```

The only tricky part is systems like FreeBSD where the system external `printf`, and the `printf` built in to `sh`, do not have `%q`.  This is less widespread than `-0` to `xargs` is.  So one has to resort to using someone else's `printf`.

```
for i in /proc/[0-9]*/
do
    basename "$i"
    < $i/cmdline xargs -0 zsh -c 'printf "\t%q" "$0" "$@"'
    printf '\n'
done
```

Observe that there's no guarantee that these are the command name and arguments that the program was started with.  Programs can change what is seen here.  You will find that a lot of them do, and they use an inferior `setproctitle()` function that mangles the argument string.  There is nothing that you can do about this.  *The individual programs themselves* have constructed a faulty argument string that puts everything into a single argument.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/432681/5132

Comment: `/proc` is not mounted by default on FreeBSD as of 12.1 (2020). there is also no `zsh` by default.

Answer (score 1):

first i should say that i assume a standard pc linux distribution for all that follows. for example, i am using a more-or-less default arch linux installation while testing.

---

```
ps -ocommand | grep \[x]ss-lock
```

...will first print series of running process command lines and then filter that list to only those that match the regex *`\[x]ss-lock`*. the *`\[x]...`* used in the regex is a fairly common work-around for handling the results race involved with listing a bunch of processes named *`xss-lock`* by filtering another list with a command containing the words *`xss-lock`*.

that's not the best way to do it, though. a linux system's `ps` is typically a [*procps-ng*](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps) `ps` which supports the `-C`ommand name filter, which, as I have been told, likely originated with AIX's `ps`.

in any case, you can drop part of the race like:

```
ps -C xss-lock -ocommand
```

...to print only those command-lines for running processes if the command name *(which you might also list like `ps -Aocomm=`)* matches `xss-lock` entirely - as a `grep -Fx` filter might do. to *actually* filter with regexes there is also the `pgrep` tool which can do similarly race-free regex matching.

---

eponymously, the *procps-ng* `ps` operates by parsing files in the `/proc` tree. for your `ps -ocommand`, for example, it reads the `/proc/$pid/cmdline` file for each match it should print and replaces the *`\0`NUL*s *(less the last - which becomes a `\n`ewline instead)* therein *(which delimit each argument in the file)* with a space each.

if you want shell-quoted argument lists you'll have to do similar. the most simple way to shell quote any list is to do it with `'` hard-quotes. it is most simple because a hard-quoted string is always flat - there's no depth-recursion in parsing because a hard-quoted string cannot contain another hard-quote. so...

```
'it'\''s not a single string'
```

...is not a single hard-quoted string, but is three concatenated strings. the first, *`it`* is surrounded on both sides by hard-quotes; the second is a single, backspace-quoted apostrophe; and the third, *s not a single string*, is hard-quoted like the first. the shell combines all three quoted-strings into a single shell *word* when parsing.

we can do the same with a `/proc/$pid/cmdline` file. we need to split each file on *`\0`NUL* bytes, pre-quote every apostrophe found therein like *`'\''`*, then surround every object with apostrophes and insert one or more `\t`ab or space characters between each.

now that i'm thinking about it, my first version of this was both needlessly complicated and, as a result, actually prone to error. intuitively i attempted to hard-quote each command's *arguments* - so all objects for a single `/proc/$pid/file` less the first - but that doesn't work *(and in, fact, completely inverts the entire resulting command-line's quote-level)* if the command name contains an odd number of apostrophes. and it doesn't matter anyway - `'cat'` works just as well as `cat` when run at a command-line. in fact, it works *better* because the first is a lot more likely to be the `cat` found in the `/proc/$pid/file` than otherwise if shell-aliases might be interpreted *(as would happen with `cat`)*.

---

so i did a similar thing to meuh's perl script, but with GNU tools. specifically, the `sed -z` option instructs a GNU `sed` to split input on *`\0`NUL* bytes rather than `\n`ewlines, and its `-s` option instructs to treat each file argument as a separate input stream *(so the `$` last line might be individually referenced for each argument and the `H`old space is reinitialized for each)*. the `ps -Csh -opid=` prints a single pid number per line for every running process matching the command name `sh`, and `sed "s|$|/cmdline|"` just appends that pathname to each.

because `$IFS` is `unset`, the *`$(cmdsub's)`* output will definitely be split by the shell into separate arguments on white-space - which is only a single `\n`ewline per pathname - and the `sed -sze` process gets an argument list of all of the `/proc/$pid/cmdline` pathnames which existed at the time `ps -C` went looking for them. this last bit reintroduces the whole race game, which is made apparent by the error message printed when `sed -sze` tries to read the *`cmdline`* file for the command sub's `sh` process which no longer exists - as it has quit by the time `sed -sze` is called at all.

---

```sh
sh -c '
    cd /proc; unset IFS
    sed  -sze "H;1h;$"\!"d;x"  \
         -e   "s/$1/&\\\\&&/g" \
         -e   "s/\x00/$1 $1/g" \
         -e   "s/.*/$1&$1\n/"  \
    $(  ps  -Csh -opid=  | 
        sed "s|$|/cmdline|")   /dev/null
' -- \'
```

---

```
'./sh' '-IE'
'sh'
'./sh' '-E'
'../sh'
'sh' '-c' '
        cd /proc; unset IFS
        sed  -sze "H;1h;$"\!"d;x"  \
             -e   "s/$1/&\\\\&&/g" \
             -e   "s/\x00/$1 $1/g" \
             -e   "s/.*/$1&$1\n/"  \
        $(  ps  -Csh -opid=  |
            sed "s|$|/cmdline|")   /dev/null
' '--' ''\'''
```

...i went through the `sh -c` embedded quoting hassle in the first place for testing, and for demonstration purposes - i needed a process that would hang around with a lot of spaced-out arguments while i ran the test.

if I drop that last empty line of input and end the quoted command just after `/dev/null` *(which is used to keep the `sed -sze` process from hijacking stdin in case of no `ps -Csome_process` results)*, the `sh -c` process *(on a system with a `dash` `sh`)* will merely `exec` `sed -sze` and replace itself with it rather than waiting to check the next line of input. in that case `sed -sze` will manage to read its own `/proc/$pid/cmdline` file - because it retains `sh -c`'s pid:

```sh
sh -c '
    cd /proc; unset IFS
    sed  -sze "H;1h;$"\!"d;x"  \
         -e   "s/$1/&\\\\&&/g" \
         -e   "s/\x00/$1 $1/g" \
         -e   "s/.*/$1&$1\n/"  \
    $(  ps  -Csh -opid=  | 
        sed "s|$|/cmdline|")   /dev/null' -- \'
```

---

```
'./sh' '-IE'
'sh'
'./sh' '-E'
'../sh'
'sed' '-sze' 'H;1h;$!d;x' '-e' 's/'\''/&\\&&/g' '-e' 's/\x00/'\'' '\''/g' '-e' 's/.*/'\''&'\''\n/' '2508/cmdline' '3773/cmdline' '5099/cmdline' '26599/cmdline' '31487/cmdline' '31488/cmdline' '31881/cmdline' '/dev/null'
sed: can't read 31488/cmdline: No such file or directory
'sh'
```

---

Here is a similar version, but it individually quotes each command entire, and stacks the escaped hard-quotes within each another layer deep:

```sh
eval "set $(
    sh -c '
        cd /proc; unset IFS
        sed  -sze "H;$"\!"d;x"                  \
             -e   "s/$1/$2\\\\$2$2/g"           \
             -e   "s/\x00\([^\x00]*\)/$2\1$2 /g"\
             -e   "s/.*/$1&$1\\\\\n /"          \
        $(  ps  -Csh -opid=  |
            sed "s|$|/cmdline|")    /dev/null
    ' -- \' "'\\\''")"
i=
for arg do printf "$arg $((i+=1)):\t%s\n" "$arg"
done;   eval "$5"
```

---

```
arg 1:  './sh' '-IE' 
arg 2:  'sh' 
arg 3:  './sh' '-E' 
arg 4:  '../sh' 
arg 5:  'sh' '-c' '
        cd /proc; unset IFS
        sed  -sze "H;$"\!"d;x"                  \
             -e   "s/$1/$2\\\\$2$2/g"           \
             -e   "s/\x00\([^\x00]*\)/$2\1$2 /g"\
             -e   "s/.*/$1&$1\\\\\n /"          \
        $(  ps  -Csh -opid=  | 
            sed "s|$|/cmdline|")   /dev/null
' '--' ''\''' ''\''\\'\'''\''' 
arg 6:  'sh' 
''\''./sh'\'' '\''-IE'\'' '\
 ''\''sh'\'' '\
 ''\''./sh'\'' '\''-E'\'' '\
 ''\''../sh'\'' '\
 ''\''sh'\'' '\''-c'\'' '\''
        cd /proc; unset IFS
        sed  -sze "H;$"\!"d;x"                  \
             -e   "s/$1/$2\\\\$2$2/g"           \
             -e   "s/\x00\([^\x00]*\)/$2\1$2 /g"\
             -e   "s/.*/$1&$1\\\\\n /"          \
        $(  ps  -Csh -opid=  |
            sed "s|$|/cmdline|")   /dev/null
'\'' '\''--'\'' '\'''\''\'\'''\'''\'' '\'''\''\'\'''\''\\'\''\'\'''\'''\''\'\'''\'''\'' '\
sed: can't read 31725/cmdline: No such file or directory
 ''\''sh'\'' '
```

Comment: @l0b0 - do you have a specific question? I guess I could have left out the `./sh '-IE'` and etc - but those are also `sh` processes running in other sessions. the point is that the `/proc/$pid/cmdline` file was read for each of the `ps -Csh -opid=` output lines so long as the associated processes still existed when the `sed -sze` process attempted to read them *(which was, for example, not true when `sed -sze` tried to read the `/proc/$(cmd sub sh pid)/cmdline` file because it quit before the `sed -sze` was up and running)*. There's always a race with `ps` queries - it's the name of the game.

Comment: OK, I'll try to line up the questions: Can you explain the first series of `sed` commands and why they're needed? `ps -Csh -opid=` fails when run on its own, so I guess it gets a process list for `$$`? How do I use this to get all processes of the current user or all processes globally? Are the extra lines of output other shells that you've started for testing purposes? Because I don't see the setup for the example you're running.

Comment: @l0bo - i'll fix it.

Comment: @l0b0 - its fixed.